# How to solve non linear optimization problem with scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I need to solve a non linear optimization problem in Python. I found out that scipy solves optimization problems, however I don't know what I am doing wrong since with some example input it can't find the correct solution that I have in [NEOS server solver Knitro AMPL](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/minco:Knitro/AMPL.html).

My problem is that, given a set of points it must find the biggest ellipse inscribed that at max touches those points and the points are never included inside of it.

**Theory**

Formulating the optimization problem, I have `a` and `b` the semiaxis, `phi` the rotation, `xc` and `yc` the coordinates of the centre and `points` the list of points with each element in the form of `[x, y] -> [0, 1]` indices.

On paper the problem and the constraints are these, `a, b, phi, xc, yc` are real, the points are integers:

[image: opt problem]

**NEOS**

The files I used in NEOS are these:

[mod](https://pastebin.com/MhHCPQB8)

[dat](https://pastebin.com/WzbVU92R)

[run](https://pastebin.com/xb2GJEA0)

With successful results ([complete](https://pastebin.com/dgPyBnUf)):

```
xc = 143.012
yc = 262.634
a = 181.489
b = 140.429
phi = 1.43575
```

**Python**

So, my python code is this, it is my first time using scipy for optimization, so I don't exclude errors of understanding how it works from the documentation.

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import *


def ellipse_calc(
    points: List[List[int]],
    verbose: bool = False
):
    centre = [0, 0]
    for i in range(len(points)):
        centre[0] += points[i][0]
        centre[1] += points[i][1]
    centre[0] /= len(points)
    centre[1] /= len(points)
    if verbose:
        print(f'centre: {centre[0]:.2f}, {centre[1]:.2f}')
    max_x = max([p[0] for p in points])
    max_y = max([p[1] for p in points])
    min_x = min([p[0] for p in points])
    min_y = min([p[1] for p in points])
    initial_axis = 0.25 * (max_x - min_x + max_y - min_y)
    if verbose:
        print(initial_axis)

    constraints = [
        NonlinearConstraint(lambda x: x[0], 1, np.inf),
        NonlinearConstraint(lambda x: x[1], 1, np.inf),
        NonlinearConstraint(lambda x: x[2], 0, np.inf),
    ]
    for i in range(len(points)):
        constraints += [NonlinearConstraint(
            lambda x:
            (points[i][0] - x[3]) ** 2 * (np.cos(x[2]) ** 2 / x[0]**2 + np.sin(x[2]) ** 2 / x[1]**2) +
            (points[i][1] - x[4]) ** 2 * (np.sin(x[2]) ** 2 / x[0]**2 + np.cos(x[2]) ** 2 / x[1]**2) +
            2 * (points[i][0] - x[3]) * (points[i][1] - x[4]) *
            np.cos(x[2]) * np.sin(x[2]) * (1 / x[1]**2 - 1 / x[0]**2), 1, np.inf)]
    result = minimize(
        lambda x: -np.pi * x[0] * x[1],
        [initial_axis, initial_axis, 0, centre[0], centre[1]],
        constraints=constraints
    )
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = [[50,44],[91,44],[161,44],[177,44],[44,88],[189,88],[239,88],[259,88],[2,132],[250,132],[2,176],[329,176],[2,220],[289,220],[2,264],[288,264],[2,308],[277,308],[2,352],[285,352],[2,396],[25,396],[35,396],[231,396],[284,396],[298,396],[36,440],[76,440],[106,440],[173,440]]
    ellipse_calc(points, True)
```

This try, that has the same data I tried on NEOS gives as output the following:

```
     fun: -8.992626773255127e+40
     jac: array([-5.68832805e+20, -4.96651566e+20, -0.00000000e+00, -0.00000000e+00,
       -0.00000000e+00])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible' 
    nfev: 54
     nit: 10
    njev: 9
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([ 1.58089104e+20,  1.81065104e+20, -1.24564497e+15, -1.55647883e+10,
       -2.76654483e+10])
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Also, I don't really know if it is possible to solve this problem with scipy, in that case I am looking for a free library to solve it or even to alternative methods of finding that ellipse equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but it should help you to get started. Here are two hints:

- Pass simple box constraints on the variables as boundaries, not as constraints. That is, use

```py
bounds = [(1, None), (1, None), (0, None), (None, None), (None, None)]
```

and pass it to `minimize` via the `bounds` parameter.

- You need to be really careful when defining constraints through lambda expressions inside a loop, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result). You need to capture the loop variable `i` by `lambda x, i=i: your_fun`. Otherwise, each of your constraints uses `i=29` and thus evaluates the last point. This can easily be observed by evaluating all constraints for a specific value.

Then you should at least get a feasible solution with an objective value of 79384. Note also that you can shorten your code significantly by using numpy functions instead of loops.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, I know I need to improve the code, it was the initial draft. Also I tried and worked, I got the same objective value as yours. I wasn't aware of the second point of the behavior of lambdas, I don't use them very often. I'll try other examples and give you the solved if all works (I hope so)